# How to access elements inside a for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm completely new to Python. I'm trying to access and print the *ith* element of an array using this code.

```
import time
from random import random

array = []
array1 = []

a = 0

for i in range(1,100000000):
    a = a + 1
    time.sleep(.2)

    x = random()

    array.append(x)
    #print(array)
    array1[a] = array[a]*0.5

    print(array[a])
```

but it gives me back this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/carlo/.PyCharmCE2019.3/config/scratches/PaulMcW(Plotting)/StoringData.py", line 17, in <module>
    array1[a] = array[a]*0.5
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I perform this simple task?

Comment: change to array1.append(array[a]*0.5)  and that should fix it

Comment: or `array1.append(x * 0.5)`

Comment: You don't need the variable `a` at all - it is essentially always equal to `i`

Comment: @Shelvington, yes you are right. But I'm trying to performing tasks between arrays, just to try this kind of operation. Also i would like to print each ith array's element and not the entire array like "print(array1)"

Comment: Is this not a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to get access to an inexistent member of your list.

```py
a = a + 1
time.sleep(.2)

x = random()
array.append(x)
array1[a] = array[a]*0.5

print(array[a])
```

`a` is equal to 1, but note that lists index start in 0, not in 1. That's why your error says "list index out of range".

The solution is to move `a = a + 1` to the end of the for loop.

```py
time.sleep(.2)

x = random()
array.append(x)
array1[a] = array[a]*0.5

print(array[a])
a = a + 1
```

However, there is another problem: You're assigning `array1[a] = array[a]*0.5` but `array1` is empty. To solve that, use the same that you used with `array`.

```py
time.sleep(.2)

x = random()
array.append(x)
array1.append(array[a]*0.5)

print(array[a])
a = a + 1
```

Comment: another wise option would be to let the for start from zero. So that we do not need an extra a 'index'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that arrays are zero-based, so `array[1]` does not yet exist when you try to access it, only `array[0]`. But there is no need for you to keep track of the length explicitly; `array[-1]` always refers to the last element of a non-empty array.

(The minimal fix is to start with `a = -1`.)

I don't think the `sleep`  adds any value, so maybe take that out, too.

```
for i in range(99999999):
    x = random()
    array.append(x)
    array1.append(x*0.5)
    print(array[a])
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to access and print the ith element of an array ...

```
# Declare an array that has elements

a = [1, 2, 3]

# loop over the elements, using the array's count
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    print(a[i])

# But usually we do it like this
# We can just iterate over the array and get each element directly
# We only need an index (i) if we care about the
# location of the element in the array
for el in a:
    print(el)
```

Note: You have a lot of other problems in your code, but I am trying to address the question you are asking about.

Often a good way for beginners to learn is to start with comments that say in English what they are trying to do, and then write the code under each comment (as I have done in the code sample above).  Get rid of anything else (like calls to `random`, `sleep`, etc)